# Normal ping between VPSs of one hoster

Tags: vps, datacenter

I use two VPS's from one hoster: one under Windows and other under Linux. I have sent ping from Windows instance to Linux and got 69ms time. I was shocked. I expected values like 1ms (as I previously asked support and got an answer that both VPSs are physically located in one network).

After that I have written to my hoster and received an answer like: "Yes, it is 69ms and it is normal". In what world is it normal?

What could be the reasons for such a big ping time (except the case that Linux and Windows VPS are located in different datacenters)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely caused by contention on one or more network devices (server nic, switch, router, etc) between the two VPSes. It *could* be caused by CPU contention on the host, but that would be very unlikely.

I should add that there is no such thing as a "normal" ping time. However, if it is true that these VPSes reside "close" to each other, a 69ms ping time seems a bit long.

Comment: Agreed. The switches in some farms are a little overworked, and getting packets from one server to another can be slow-ish if there are a lot of data-intensive websites or medias being hosted. I would complain, if it really bothers you, and maybe they can move you to two close-to-eachother servers.